# Replacement using pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Starting with the expression

```
eq1 = 5 Exp[1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3];
```

I want to implement the following transformation:

```
eq1 /.  Exp[a_ x^2 + b_ x^3] ->   f[a/b]
```

However, I am not getting the desired output
$5 f[3/4]\exp(1+2 x)$.

Further, I also need to perform the following transformation.

```
eq2 = c Exp[a SuperStar[\[Alpha]] + b \[Alpha]];
eq2 /. d1_ Exp[d2 SuperStar[\[Alpha]_]] -> f[d2]
```

I am providing the above expressions again in latex font for clarification.
 $$
\text{eq2}=c \exp \left(a \alpha ^*+\alpha  b\right);
$$

$$
\text{eq2}\text{/.}\, \text{d1$\_$} \exp \left(\alpha \_{}^* \text{d2}\right)\to f(\text{d2})
$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
eq1 /. Exp[a_. x^2 + b_. x^3 + c_.] -> Exp[c] f[a/b]
```

> 5 E^(1 + 2 x) f[3/4]

```
eq2 /. d1_. Exp[d2_. SuperStar[α_] + d3_.] -> Exp[d3] f[d2]
```

> E^(b α) f[a]

Comment: If you use defaults in the replacement pattern (dots after the patterns), they become more versatile: `Exp[a_. x^2 + b_. x^3 + c_.] -> Exp[c] f[a/b]`. This will also work with `eq1a = 5 Exp[x^2 + 4 x^3]`, for example. Also, `d1_. Exp[d2_. SuperStar[α_] + d3_.] -> Exp[d3] f[d2]` for the second one.

Comment: @Roman, great point. Updated with default patterns.

Comment: @Shadowray, thank you; I added the needed `_.`s.